# Determine if the function is $O(x^2)$ . If so find the constants $C$ and $k$ to verify.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

Determine if $ f(x) = 4x^2+x+1$ is $O(x^2)$. If so find the constants $C$ and $k$ to verify that the function is $O(x^2)$

My solution is:

\begin{align}
& |f(x)| \le  C|x^2| \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x > k\\[8pt]
&|4x^2+x+1| \le C(x^2)  \ \forall x > 1 \\[8pt]
& 4x^2+x+1 \le 4x^2 +x^2+x^2  \ \ \ \forall x > 1\\[8pt]
& 4x^2+x+1 \le 6(x^2)\\[8pt]
& k=1 \text{ and } C=6 \\[8pt]
& f(x) = O(x^2)
\end{align}

Is this correct? Im unsure of my methodology.

Answer (score 1):

That Inequality is certainly true and your methodology seems correct, however I am curious as to why the question asks you to find "the constants $C$ and $k$," as opposed to just "constants $C$ and $k$." For example, a similar methodology could yield $C$ = 5 and $k$ = 2.
$$ \begin{align}
& |f(x)| \le  C|x^2| \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x > k\\[8pt]
&|4x^2+x+1| \le C(x^2)  \ \forall x > 2 \\[8pt]
& 4x^2+x+1 \le 4x^2 + x^2  \ \ \ \forall x > 2\\[8pt]
& 4x^2+x+1 \le 5(x^2)\\[8pt]
& k=2 \text{ and } C=5 \\[8pt]
\end{align}$$